Who covered The Cure's "Boys Don't Cry" in the film "Boys Don't Cry"?
The 1999 film Boys Don't Cry features a cover of "Boys Don't Cry" by The Cure.
From the "Boys Don't Cry" (film) Wikipedia article:

An American cover of the song plays in the background in two scenes: when Lana bails Brandon out of jail, and the scene in which the two make love in the car, where it is heard at a low volume in the background. However, the song is not included on the released soundtrack.

Who performed this cover version?

A cover version, performed by Nathan Larson, was used as the title song of the 1999 film Boys Don't Cry.

Do you have a source for this? The only info I can find in the Boys Don't Cry Wikipedia article about this is: Nathan Larson and Nina Persson of The Cardigans composed an instrumental version of Restless Heart's 1988 country-pop hit "The Bluest Eyes in Texas".

Song's wiki page. Give a look.

Doh! Never thought to look at that article. I just checked out the film's Wikipedia article.

I would appreciate if someone could share a link where we can listen to this cover version of the song.
